# AJAX Request doesn't update the second table (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have 2 Tables - car producer and car model. I pull data from a database. When I click on a producer in the first table I want the second table to show only cars from this producer. I tried to use ajax for that but the ajax request doesnt seem to override the $DBcontent variable so that the second table doesnt get filtered.
But when I use console.log(data); on succedeed Ajax it shows the correct records.
Am I misunderstanding something? I left out the SQL queries because they are simple and irrelevant.

Controller CarListController.php :

```
<?php

class CarListController extends CI_Controller 
{   
    public function index()
    {
                $this->load->model('OutputFromDatabaseModel');
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                $query = $this->OutputFromDatabaseModel->getProducers();
                $DBcontent['PROD'] =  $query;
                $query = $this->OutputFromDatabaseModel->getCars(); // fill with all Cars first
                $DBcontent['CARS'] =  $query; 

                $this->load->view('CarListView', $DBcontent);
    }  
}
?>
```

View CarListView.php :

```
<script>
var URL = "(myURL)/index.php/Process/FilterCars";
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".test").click(function(e) //row from Producer table
    {
        $ID = this.id;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: {id:$ID},
                dataType    : "json",
            });

        showModels = true;
        if (showModels) // only show the car models table when clicked on a producer
        {
            document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display="";
        }         
    });
});
</script>
<body>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
    <table id="producerTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
     <tr><td><strong>Producer</strong></td></tr> 
     <?php foreach($PROD as $producer){?>
     <tr class="test" id="<?=$producer->ProducerID?>"><td><?=$producer->ProducerName;?></td></tr>     
        <?php }?>  
    </table>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <table id="modelTable" style="display:none" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
     <tr><td><strong>Car Model</strong></td></tr> 
     <?php foreach($CARS as $car){?>
     <tr id="<?=$car->CarId?>"><td><?=$car->Model;?></td></tr>     
        <?php }?>  
    </table>
   </div> 
</body>
```

AjaxProcess Process.php :

```
<?php
class Process extends CI_Controller 
{   
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('CarListView', $DBcontent); //tried to put it everywhere 
    }  
    function FilterCars(){
        $this->load->model('OutputFromDatabaseModel');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $ProducerID = $this->input->post('id');
        $query = $this->OutputFromDatabaseModel->getCarsOfProducer($ProducerID); //filtered by Producer
        $DBcontent['CARS'] =  $query;
    }
}
?>
```

How do I launch the View with updated $DBcontent variable? What are the alternatives if its a wrong approach.

Comment: Hi @Mark, your second table probably still display all the car, because your ajax request doesn't do anything, it just post the data to server, you didn't use the data it returns. you just set the "modelTable" to be visible after ajaxcall

Answer (score 0):

Your second table probably still display all the car, because your ajax request doesn't do anything, it just post the data to server, you didn't use the data it returns. you just set the "modelTable" to be visible after ajax call.
Refer to the `success` function in Jquery Ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$(".test").click(function(e) //row from Producer table
   {
    $ID = this.id;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: {id:$ID},
            dataType    : "json",
            success:function(data){ // function to call when the ajax call sucessful
            // i simply replace the content of the table with the response with ajax, 
            //you can use the data to create html here and append it into the table.
            $('#modelTable').html(data); 

            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: I used the success function and it kinda worked. Thats kind of something I was looking for but I still have some problems. 


- dataType  : "json", doesnt work and I had to remove it
- what do I have to output in Process.php ? As mentioned before echo json_encode($DBcontent); just really doesnt work for me and just outputs the arrays and not html for a table..

I got the output just right by using an aditional php file with just a table in it and then getting the html from the loaded view, but whats the right way to to that?